# Run React-Native UWP error

Tags: react-native

I am trying to run React-Native for UWP on windows 10. I follow the instructions here https://www.microsoft.com/reallifecode/2016/05/26/creating-universal-windows-apps-with-react-native/#comment-180

When I get to last step (Running the Universal Windows App), it throws error when I run the command

```
react-native run-windows
```

The error I get is

```
Starting the React-Native Server
Failed to deploy: path must be a string or Buffer
```

I tried google this error. I don't think there is much on React-Native UWP, and this error hasn't came up before.

Comment: Try to run it from Visual Studio. Open the solution and run it, and then in a console, run `react-native start`.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer pointed me in right direction for the solution.

Comment: Glad to hear it! Please mark your answer as accepted so that the question gets closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

Open the Solution in Visual Studio. Set up the Build so that it works on my machine (make sure solution platform and solution configurations are correct).

From now on, running that command should work with no issues.